# Splitting a string to find words between delimiters?

Tags: python

Given a certain line that looks like this:

```
jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpsasword=12345&
```

I want to return the username and password, in this case being `Bob` and `12345`.

I tried splitting the string by the & sign but could not figure out how to then find the individual words, and then also tried the below code:

```
left='password='
right='&'
userleft='username='
for x in file.readlines():
    if 'password=' and 'username=' in x:
        text=str(x)
        #password=(text[text.index(left)+len(left):text.index(right)])
        #username=(text[text.index(userleft)+len(userleft):text.index(useright)])
```

Comment: Please  post the contents of the input, and your complete runnable program as well its output, if any.

Comment: @C.Pappy. Input is already shown and clearly the output is not useful given that OP is asking for help to achieve it.

Comment: `if 'password=' and 'username=' in x` doesn't do what you think it does. Related: [Why does `a == b or c or d` always evaluate to True?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/843953)
and [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/843953)

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions, you can split twice: once on `&` and once on `=`:

```
line = 'jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpsasword=12345&'
items = [item.split('=') for item in line.split('&')]
```

Now you can extract the values:

```
for item in items:
    if len(item) == 2:
        if item[0].endswith('password'):
            password = item[1]
        elif item[0].endswith('username'):
            username = item[1]
```

If you had a bunch of keys you were looking for, like `('username', 'password')`, you could write a nested loop to build dictionaries:

```
keys = ('username', 'password')
result = {}
for item in items:
    if len(item) == 2:
        for k in keys:
            if item[0].endswith(k):
                result[k] = item[1]
                break
```

This makes it a lot easier to check that you got all the values you want, e.g. with `if len(keys) == len(result): ...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very simple approach, you could do this:

```
data = 'jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpassword=12345&'

#right of "username=" and left of "&"
un = data.split('username=')[1].split('&')[0]

#right of "password=" and left of "&"
pw = data.split('password=')[1].split('&')[0]

print(un, pw) #Bob, 12345
```

Since the process is identical except for the desired key, you could do something like the below and homogenize the process of getting the value for any key in the query. An interesting side-effect of this is: Even if your example query did not end in "&", this would still work. This is because everything that is left would be in the result of `.split('&')[0]`, and there simply wouldn't be a `.split('&')[1]`. Nothing below uses `.split('&')[1]` so, it just wouldn't matter.

```
query = 'jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpassword=12345&'

key2val = lambda q,k: q.split(f'{k}=')[1].split('&')[0]

un = key2val(query, 'username')
pw = key2val(query, 'password')

print(un, pw) #Bob, 12345
```

This method is likely superior to regex. It is bound to be faster, it doesn't require any dependencies or loops, and it is flexible enough to allow you to get the value from any key, regardless of order, without the need to ever change anything.

Comment: Please don't assign anonymous function to a name, it's considered a bad style in general - if you need a named function, define it with `def`, and lambda's are called anonymous for reason:)

Comment: There is no reason why this needs to be a definition. `labdas` have a purpose and this is one of them.

Comment: This has only minor runtime implications, just a matter of code style enforced by PEP8 (bullet 5 [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations))

Comment: I already know, my friend. I also know that the lambda ceased to be anonymous the second I bound it to a keyword, and the compiled version of this code would be identical to it's counterpart with a definition. `lambda`s can contain one expression and they return the results of that expression. My use of  `lambda` means "this is it, nothing left to do and no room for modification". It a lot of ways it is no different than the suggestion that "_dont_touch" is somehow protected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
import re
for x in file.readlines():
    if 'password=' in x and 'username=' in x:
        text=str(x)
        username = re.findall('username=(\w+)',text)
        password = re.findall('password=(\w+)',text)
```

Note the updated `if` statement. In the orginal, the `if` checks if `"password="` evaluates to `True`, which it always will - since it is not an empty string.

Comment: `readlines()` is redundant by the way, and could result in excessive memory use by reading the whole file at once. Iterating over the file itself will give it to you line by line.

Comment: Not sure `\w+` is appropriate for the regular expression, it prevents you from having punctuation in the username or password.

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 0):

Update #2

This reads a file named "text" and parses out the username and password for each line if they both exist.

This solution assumes that the username and password fields both end with a "&".

Update #3:

Note that this code will work even if the order of the username and password is reversed.

```
import re
with open('text') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
        # Note that ([^&]+) captures any characters up to the next &.
        m1 = re.search('username=([^&]+)', line)
        m2 = re.search('password=([^&]+)', line)
        if m1 and m2:
            print('username=', m1[1])
            print('password=', m2[1])
```

Output:

```
jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpassword=12345&
username= Bob
password= 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single regular expression to parse this information out:

```py
import re

s = "jfdajfjlausername=Bob&djfkaak;jdskjpassword=12345&"
regex = "username=(?P<username>.+)&.*password=(?P<password>.+)&"
match = re.search(regex, s)

print(match.groupdict())
{'username': 'Bob', 'password': '12345'}
```

Implementing this while looping over the lines in a file would look like:

```py
regex = "username=(?P<username>.+)&.*password=(?P<password>.+)&"

with open('text') as f:
    for line in f:
  
        match = re.search(regex, line)
        if match is not None:
            print(match.groupdict())
```